# Two backups from different AppleID’s which were encrypted with two different passwords merged together in one encrypted backup

Tags: iphone, backup, apple-id

After my iphone broke down, I borrowed a friend’s iphone for some time. I have backed up his AppleID using **his** password on my macbook and restored my latest backup on his iphone. There were **two separate** backups with our names as iOS files on macbook storage. After I bought a new iphone, I made a backup again on the same macbook. When the backup finished, there were no longer two separate backups - they merged into **one with my name on it**. The size of that backup matched the size of two backups combined. When restoring, it asks for a password and accepts only mine, the friend’s password appears as incorrect. It restores only my data. Apple support doesn’t know the solution for breaking those backups apart. I’ve tried to use a lot of software which is supposed to extract files from the backup folder, but again, all of these **requires password and shows only my data**. Is there any chance to restore my friend’s data? Most importantly photos.

Comment: Do you run periodic backups of your Mac to restore the backup files from before the merge?

Comment: no, my Mac was not backed up before merge :(

Comment: That’s the only think I could think of - let’s see if anyone else know if the restore / replacement didn’t totally overwrite the only copy of those photos.

Comment: Can you include some screenshots of where you see the merged backup? - I have never heard of backups merging together, so it might be that you're looking in the wrong place, and can access his backup some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Here are places you might have a backup copy.

1. iCloud (you can look online with a web browser and a computer)
2. Time Machine backups if Mac sync or backup the phone data. Windows equivalent for that computer.
3. Contact Apple Support in case they can see an iCloud backup that you can not.